# Is RAM/HDD Shared on Tablets PCs?

Tags: tablet

First off, this isn't directly Android related, I browsed through the humongous list of Stack sites but couldn't find a better fit. If this isn't allowed, move/delete/eat this post before reading on.

Now - how does Tablet RAM work? Is the hard drive (SSD?) shared with the system memory? I can't seem to find any info on this.

Comment: We do expect questions to be directly Android related, yes.

Answer (score 3):

No, RAM is RAM, hard drive space is separate. A smokingly fast SSD would be much slower than typical RAM sticks, and it would be impractical to run a system like that. Even smartphones have real RAM sticks in them (usually [LPDDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_DDR)).